# AutoHotKey - ImageSearch Two Images

Tags: autohotkey

Is there any way to have the ImageSearch command on AutoHotKey look for two images

Currently my code is this:

```
Loop
{
ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 664, 556, 1364, 924, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\continue.PNG
If ! ErrorLevel
    {
        Click %wherexis%,%whereyis%
        break
    }
}
Sleep, 1400
```

Sometimes the screen displays on image and other times it displays another so oftentimes my code stops running since it cannot find the image. How can I make an "or" kind of statement to make the ImageSearch look for two images and click whatever shows up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do another imagesearch in case the first one wasn't found:

```
Loop 
{ 
    ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 664, 556, 1364, 924, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\continue.PNG 
    If ! ErrorLevel 
    { ;If the first image was found:
        Click %wherexis%,%whereyis% 
        break 
    } 
    Else 
    { ;If the first image was not found:
        ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 664, 556, 1364, 924, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\image2.PNG 
        If ! ErrorLevel 
        { ;If the second image was found:
            Click %wherexis%,%whereyis% 
            break 
        }
    }
    Sleep, 100
} 
Sleep, 1400
```